# How to save the color changed with checkbox to load after refreshing the page

Tags: php, session, cookies

Morning guys. I am trying to make a "checker" to know what bosses from Guild Wars 2 I already did today and I have a little problem with remembering the colors I changed using the checkboxes. I have a table of bosses loaded from the database and it's default color is red. When you check the checkbox the whole  turns green. This part worked so far. The problem is it goes back to red when you refresh the page. The checkbox remains checked but the color goes back to default. I guess it could be done using cookies or session but since I never used it before I am kinda lost.

```
<?php
  include 'joinDB.php';
  $dotaz="SELECT `name`, `zone`, `map`, `wplink` FROM `bosses`
  ORDER BY `name` ASC";
  $vysledek=mysqli_query($spojeni, $dotaz, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);      
  $checkID = 1;
  while(list($name, $zone, $map, $wplink)=mysqli_fetch_array($vysledek)) {      
  echo "
  <tr id='$checkID' style=\"background-color:#fa6361\">
  <td style='width:200px'>$name</td>
  <td style='width:160px'>$zone</td>   
  <td style='width:160px'>$map</td>
  <td>$wplink</td>
  <td><form method='post'><input id='checkBoxesRow' type='checkbox' onclick=\"document.getElementById('$checkID').style.backgroundColor=this.checked?'#90AF0F':'#fa6361'\" ><br/></form></td>
  </tr>
  ";      
  $checkID++;
  }  
?>
```

I used this to change the color when checked. I tried searching for the answer but so far I did not find the way to use the solutions I found to get my code working ... All answers appreciated :)

Comment: you could either update the db table to indicate the record has been "done", use `cookies` or `localStorage`

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I don't want to use DB as it would require to submit and refresh to get values. And since I have never used cookies or session I don't know how to store this kind of data in that.

Comment: I'd say that you should have 1 form only and each checkbox should have a listener function registered to process the click. The listener should then update te `localStorage` with json style data which gets read on page load. MDN has some good articles on `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Ha, perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

A quickly put together example of using `localStorage` to retain state of the checkboxes. This ought to be easy to integrate with your existing code - substitute suitable `data-id` values such as `$name`

```
echo "<form id='guildwars' method='post'>
    <table>";
/* This should be your db results being looped through */
for( $i=0; $i < 10; $i++ ){
    $id="boss_$i";
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>\$NAME</td>
            <td>\$ZONE</td>
            <td>\$MAP</td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' data-id='$id' /></td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "
    </table>
</form>";


<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
    var store='guildwars';

    function bindEvents(){
        var col=document.getElementById( 'guildwars' ).querySelectorAll( 'input[type="checkbox"]' );
        var oStore=JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( store ) );

        if( col )for( var n in col )if( col[n].nodeType==1 ){
            /* assign listener to the checkbox */
            col[n].addEventListener( 'click', register, false );

            /* obtain reference to parent table row */
            var tr=col[n].parentNode.parentNode;

            /* assign pale red to indicate `not done` */
            setcolour(tr,0);

            /* re-tick previously selected checkboxes */
            if( oStore!=null && oStore.indexOf( col[n].dataset.id )!=-1 ){
                col[n].checked=true;
                setcolour(tr,1);
            }
        }
    }

    function setcolour(n,i){
        n.style.backgroundColor=i==1 ? '#90AF0F' : '#fa6361';
    }

    function register(event){
        var el=event.target;
        var tr=el.parentNode.parentNode;
        var id=el.dataset.id;

        oStore=localStorage.getItem( store )!=null ? JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( store ) ) : [];
        if( el.checked ) {
            oStore.push( id );
            setcolour(tr,1);
        } else {
            oStore.splice( oStore.indexOf( id ),1 );
            setcolour(tr,0);
        }
        localStorage.setItem( store, JSON.stringify( oStore ) );
    }

    /* bind the event listeners */
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',bindEvents,false);
</script>
```